# How to fix this error "combineReducers" are read-only. in react-native/react-redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm creating a new todo app in react-native using redux.
On setting up the rootReducer using combineReducers i'm getting the following error.

"combineReducers" is read-only.

[image: "combineReducers" is read-only.]

```
// reducers/todos.js

let nextId = 0;
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'ADD_TODO':

            return [
                ...state, {
                    id: nextId++,
                    text: action.text,
                    completed: false,
                }
            ]

        case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
            return state.map(todo =>
                (todo.id === action.id) ? { ...todos, completed: !todo.completed } : todo)

        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default todos;
```

created a visibility filter to toggle the todo state.

```
// reducers/visibilityFilter.js

const visibilityFilter = (state='SHOW_ALL', action) =>{
    return state;
}

export default visibilityFilter;
```

combining the both reducers into index file.

```
// reducers/index.js 

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import todos from './todos';
import visibilityFilter from './visibilityFilter';

export default combineReducers = combineReducers({
    todos,
    visibilityFilter
})
```

Here is my store file

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message clearly states, you are not allowed to reassign `combineReducers`. Just change your code to the following, as described in [the docs](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers):

```
export default rootReducer = combineReducers({
    todos,
    visibilityFilter
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this like this?

```
export default combineReducers = combineReducers({
    todos,
    visibilityFilter
})
```

`combineReducers()` are written in this manner:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

export default combineReducers({
  todos: () => {
    return {};
  }
});
```

Give that a try and remember a reducer must always return an object, a string or a number, this is the minimum requirement for getting started with reducers in order to ensure your app doesn't break and that you can get some content to the screen.

Also, you don't necessarily need to identify your `combineReducers()` as `rootReducer`, you can just put it together like so:

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "../reducers";

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

Lastly, when you have created your `store`, you need to import it back to your `App.js` and wire it up with the `Provider` tag like so for example:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from "react-navigation";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import store from "./store";
```

And:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MainNavigator />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```